# Is it possible to access/tunnel through my virtual machine(vmware fusion) from my local machine where it is running?

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine

I'm running vmware fusion and was wondering if its possible to to access the centos running on my virtual machine like I would access a regular server?

Maybe through ssh or an ip address?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is.  On the virtual machine use `ifconfig` or `ipconfig`to find out the IP address it uses.  You should be able to use that IP address.

Now, depending on the OS in the virtual machine, you may need to enable services, eg make sure you're running the needed daemon for ssh or enable telnet.  Check the OS documentation (can you say "google?" for details.)